# Getting type of items of a List at run-time in c#

Tags: c#, linq, runtime, expression, gettype

I need an expression that gets type of every item of a collection.

I have a collection like this:

```
var collection = new List<object>{1,2.2,"string",'c'};
```

It's possible to get type of every item of collection like this:

```
var myVariable= collection.Select(item => item.GetType())
```

But I need creation of this expression at run-time.
I have to create something like `myVariable` dynamically, but how?!

Debugger shows me value of internal expression of `myVariable` like this:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Object,System.Type]}
```

**EDIT1**

Explanation of problem:
Assume that I need to select one property of an object. I cat write this query like this:

```
var lst = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass {Name = "myName1", Value = 1},
            new MyClass {Name = "myName2", Value = 2}
        };
        var oneProperty = lst.Select(item => new {SelectedProp=item.Name});
```

result is a list of type anonymous contains 2 items: "myName1"&"myName2".
Now I want to add another property to resulted list that shows the type of selected property. The following code gets me thus list:

```
            var oneProperty = lst.Select(item => new {SelectedProp=item.Name,TypeOfProp=item.GetType() });
```

The problem is to create such expression at run-time to give the expression to entity framework and it executes the expression. Is the problem cleared?

Comment: Show us in pseudo-code what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Given that the proposed solutions do not answer your problem, please clarify what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Post edited and problem explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your recent edit, here's how to compile an expression such as the following at run-time:

```
item => new AnonymousType() { SelectProp = item.name, TypeOfProp = item.GetType() }
```

---

I've added comments to show how the expression is being constructed. You can adapt this to your needs.

```
[Fact]
public void CreateExpression()
{
    Type argType = typeof (MyClass);
    string propertyName = "Name";

    ParameterExpression paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(argType, "item");

    //Create "item.Name" and "item.GetType()" expressions
    var propertyAccessExpression = Expression.Property(paramExpression, propertyName); 
    var getTypeExpression = Expression.Call(paramExpression, "GetType", Type.EmptyTypes);

    Type anonType = CreateAnonymousType<String, Type>("SelectedProp", "TypeOfProp");

    //"SelectProp = item.name"
    MemberBinding assignment1 = Expression.Bind(anonType.GetField("SelectedProp"), propertyAccessExpression);
    //"TypeOfProp = item.GetType()"
    MemberBinding assignment2 = Expression.Bind(anonType.GetField("TypeOfProp"), getTypeExpression);

    //"new AnonymousType()"
    var creationExpression = Expression.New(anonType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

    //"new AnonymousType() { SelectProp = item.name, TypeOfProp = item.GetType() }"
    var initialization = Expression.MemberInit(creationExpression, assignment1, assignment2);

    //"item => new AnonymousType() { SelectProp = item.name, TypeOfProp = item.GetType() }"
    Expression expression = Expression.Lambda(initialization, paramExpression);
}
```

You'll need this method to create a new anonymous type:

```
public static Type CreateAnonymousType<TFieldA, TFieldB>(string fieldNameA, string fieldNameB)
{
    AssemblyName dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName("TempAssembly");
    AssemblyBuilder dynamicAssembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    ModuleBuilder dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("TempAssembly");

    TypeBuilder dynamicAnonymousType = dynamicModule.DefineType("AnonymousType", TypeAttributes.Public);

    dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(fieldNameA, typeof(TFieldA), FieldAttributes.Public);
    dynamicAnonymousType.DefineField(fieldNameB, typeof(TFieldB), FieldAttributes.Public);

    return dynamicAnonymousType.CreateType();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Objects like `myVariable` implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Thus, you can retrieve the interface and get the element type as the generic parameter:

```
var type = myVariable.GetType();
foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
{
    if (i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    {
        return i.GetGenericTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
// not a generic collection
return typeof(object);
```

**Edit:** Or do you only need the types of the elements? You can achieve this with a cast to `IEnumerable<object>` since the type parameter of `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant.

```
collection.Cast<object>().Select(o => o.GetType())
```

Comment: Thanks Georg, But I need to create an expression dynamically! Your answer doesn't create any expression at run-time.

Comment: you can use the type retrieved from this code and call the Select extension method with the appropriate type parameter

Comment: I need to create an expression that by executing it, myVariable be filled.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate the List to get the actual Type:

```
    var collection = new List<object> { 1, 2.2, "string", 'c' };
    var myVariable = collection.Select(item => item.GetType());

    foreach(var m in myVariable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.FullName);
    }
```

EDIT:

The Type you're seeing in the debugger:

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Object,System.Type]}
```

is the runtime type of the Linq query represented by myVariable. You need to iterate such a query in order to get the individual values.
Cheers

Comment: It's just an example to show that within a foreach loop, you will be able to get the actual Type you're looking for.

Comment: Mrlucmorin thank you, You assume that the value of myVariable is provided by "Select" function. But the problem is to create something named "Expression" that gets result of "Select" function at run-time.

Comment: @Merta I don't want to be rude or anything, but the more you explain, the less I understand. Please take a step back and try to think about how to word your problem in such a way that we can understand. Obviously nobody understands what you're trying to do.