# How to create expression at run-time

Tags: c#, expression, gettype

I have a class contains 4 properties:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int i{get;set;}
    public double d{get;set;}
    public string s{get;set;}
    public char c{get;set;}
}
```

And a list of this class:

```
var lstSource = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass {i = 1, d = 1.2, s = "s1", c = '1'},
    new MyClass {i = 2, d = 2.2, s = "s2", c = '2'},
    new MyClass {i = 3, d = 3.2, s = "s3", c = '3'}
};
```

Now I want to get name of some of these properties from end-user and gets him a list of type anonymous contains wanted properties. User gives us list of wanted properties as a collection of string (name of wanted properties). For example assume list of wanted properties is like this:

```
var wantedProperties = new List<string> {"i", "s"};
```

- Problem1: How to get only these properties from `lstSource`?
- Problem2: How to provide type of every property as new variable in anonymous list? For every item in "wantedProperties" it most add another variable to resulted list hat shows type of wanted property. At this example resulted list most be like this:

  ```
  {
      {WantedProperty1_Value = 1,WantedProperty1_Type = typeof(int)},
      {WantedProperty2_Value = 2,WantedProperty2_Type = typeof(string)}
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your `MyClass` has fields, not properties. You'll have to change those to `public int i {get; set;}`, for example.

Now, you can use reflection to get the *value* and *type* of a property identified by its name.

```
foreach(MyClass obj in lstSource)
{
    foreach(string propertyName in wantedProperties)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(propertyName);

        object value = property.GetValue(obj);
        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    }
}
```

If the property is not public, you'll have to use a [different overload of `GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek55ae84%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` binding flags.

Now all you have to do is build the result set.

Comment: Ow, I'm wacky :-| You are right and those members of class are fields.

Comment: This solution works, Thank you, But I need create an Expression and pass the Expression to MyExpressionRunner to get data from entity framework. Can I get help for creating an Expression that does this work?

Comment: That's a different question that can't easily be answered in a comment.. Please post a new question. Also, illustrate your input data, and the expected output data (what the actual expression would look like).

Comment: I have asked this in another post, but unfortunately nobody understood the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878344/getting-type-of-items-of-a-list-at-run-time-in-c-sharp/21878610?noredirect=1#comment33127136_21878610

Comment: @Merta I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks @dcastro! I saw your great help at my primary question. It was helpful :)